# opt with irtranslator pass crashes

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

When I run opt with the irtranslator pass, I keep getting segfaults. Here's a variation of what I've been running:

```
opt -debug -mcpu=x86-64 -S sample.bc --irtranslator
```

**Some other notes**:

- sample.bc is a simple hello world function I compiled into llvm bytecode with clang
- some passes such as --instcombine do work
- I'm using a version of llvm built from source

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
LLVM version 11.0.0git
DEBUG build with assertions.
Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Host CPU: haswell
```

**Stack Trace**:

```
    Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: ../llvm10/build/bin/opt -debug -mcpu=x86-64 -S sample.bc --x86-codegen
 #0 0x00007fec32c271c7 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:564:0
 #1 0x00007fec32c2725a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:625:0
 #2 0x00007fec32c24ff5 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() llvm/lib/Support/Signals.cpp:68:0
 #3 0x00007fec32c26b44 SignalHandler(int) llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:406:0
 #4 0x00007fec2dff2890 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x12890)
 #5 0x00007fec31c6e750 llvm::MachineModuleInfo::MachineModuleInfo(llvm::LLVMTargetMachine const*) llvm/lib/CodeGen/MachineModuleInfo.cpp:194:0
 #6 0x00007fec31c6eddb llvm::MachineModuleInfoWrapperPass::MachineModuleInfoWrapperPass(llvm::LLVMTargetMachine const*) llvm/lib/CodeGen/MachineModuleInfo.cpp:295:0
 #7 0x00007fec31c7099b llvm::Pass* llvm::callDefaultCtor<llvm::MachineModuleInfoWrapperPass>() llvm/include/llvm/PassSupport.h:80:0
 #8 0x00007fec32192938 llvm::PassInfo::createPass() const llvm/include/llvm/PassInfo.h:102:0
 #9 0x00007fec3218a9a2 llvm::PMTopLevelManager::schedulePass(llvm::Pass*) llvm10/llvm/lib/IR/LegacyPassManager.cpp:702:0
#10 0x00007fec3218aa07 llvm::PMTopLevelManager::schedulePass(llvm::Pass*) llvm/lib/IR/LegacyPassManager.cpp:706:0
#11 0x00007fec321933de llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::add(llvm::Pass*) llvm/lib/IR/LegacyPassManager.cpp:500:0
#12 0x00007fec3218f709 llvm::legacy::PassManager::add(llvm::Pass*) llvm/lib/IR/LegacyPassManager.cpp:1721:0
#13 0x00007fec2ff8650d OptCustomPassManager::add(llvm::Pass*) llvm/tools/opt/opt.cpp:340:0
#14 0x00007fec2ff7e9de addPass(llvm::legacy::PassManagerBase&, llvm::Pass*) llvm/tools/opt/opt.cpp:375:0
#15 0x00007fec2ff81013 main llvm/tools/opt/opt.cpp:862:0
#16 0x00007fec2cc51b97 __libc_start_main /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:344:0
#17 0x00007fec2ff5150a _start (../llvm10/build/bin/opt+0x195150a)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

IRTranslator is a pass used during the codegeneration. You're not supposed to run it directly via opt.